# Delay ON LED circuit with motion sensor OFF

Tags: led-strip, delay, circuits

I'm trying to make a circuit that goes:

> Delay ON > Run for 5 minutes > Off.

But it also has a motion detector that will immediately switch the circuit off when it detects motion. I am referring to this circuit diagram for the Delay ON part:
[image]

*https://circuitspedia.com/on-delay-timer-circuit-diagram-with-relay-using-capacitor/*

But other than that, I'm at a loss on how to integrate the motion sensor part. Can anyone please help? I'm new but I'm willing to learn. I am using 12V batteries and some LED strips (120 led/m).

Comment: First: I can see how the circuit starts with delay. How does it turn off after 5 minutes? After it starts, it will run forever;


Second: What kind of motion sensor do you want? The one with digital output, I presume? Motion detected - 5V output, no motion - 0V (or reversed); or some other kind of sensor?

Comment: Generating long (i.e. 5 minutes) using discrete electronic components can be very tricky.  Have you looked at the common 555 timer IC?  But if I were tasked with this I would likely choose a low-cost microcontroller such at a Microchip (Atmel) ATTINY.

Comment: Also, what kind of components can you use? A comparator with an RC tank could work for timing stuff, but 5 minutes is so much that I'm afraid R and C will have to be too big to be stable; Your task number 1 at the moment is to measure 5 minutes. A microcontroller board like arduino can do that, if you don't mind a microcontroller in your design (which will also remove almost all other componets from the circuit since you can control all that hardware through 5 lines of code in arduino)

Comment: If a microcontroller is not an option for you, your task can be accomplished with 555 timers and logic gates.  To get a long timing like 5 minutes you just need a decent modern 555 chip and a decent, fairly large timing capacitor.  You use a 555 one shot timer to create a delay pulse, logic chips to produce a falling edge detection trigger for the second 555, which is also set up in one shot mode for the 5 minute pulse.  If your load is more than the 555 can support, attach an NMOSFET to the control pin.

Comment: That said your question might be a bit too broad and you might want to try an easier timing or logic project first.  If you want to get a solderless breadboard and some parts and chips to try experimenting, MOSFET based(as opposed to older TTL) chips like 555 timers and logic gates are really easy to work with as the high impedance inputs let you forego resistors at first and simply concentrate on figuring out the logic you need.

Comment: Search for c005 timer. Cheap solution. http://westsideelectronics.com/delay-timer-ic/

Comment: @Ilya I have done more research and I know a bit about the 555. Initially, my idea was to use two 555 chips so one would be the delay ON and the other would help with the timer? But since you brought up Arduino and the size issue of the RC, perhaps a more logical way is to just use code to replace the RCs.

Comment: Or one can use a low freq oscillator, a counter and some logic gates.

Comment: @Ilya regarding the motion sensor, it's the reverse. I want the circuit to be off when there is motion.

Comment: @jwh20 Yep, after some more research, my idea now is to use the 555 chips to deal with the timing. Are you suggesting using a microcontroller to help with the 5 mins?

Comment: @KH Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I have no choice but to go ahead with this project. Actually, I was going to go ahead with the two 555 IC chips that you've suggested, but now I am also considering microcontrollers.

Comment: you definitely don't need TWO timer chips. You can easily measure 5s with RC circuit. And you replied my question incorrectly. The question was about sensor's output, it can output always 5V and 0V when motion or the other way around, but it doesn't matter in the end. It's just a trigger signal.
MCU is a good option. I would put MCU to deep sleep so that it doesn't consume almost anything (microamps, if done smart, even dozen nanoamps for some). And any kind of activity just wakes it up, it does the thing and back to sleep again.

Comment: The reason I recommend 555s is the total knowledge base is smaller than doing your first microcontroller project.  That said, once you have the basics of a microcontroller down, the overall difficulty level of a massive variety of projects is greatly reduced by the capabilities of the microcontroller.  You'll still need to learn a bit about circuits to attach things to the microcontroller, but you can accomplish a lot by learning about and adding new components piecewise.